# PSTN and Internet

Tags: networking, internet, telephony, pstn

Where Is Physical Wires Exist for Internet Is It Using PSTN Wires for Transferring Data? If both are different network then How Telecom Companies Are Providing Internet Facility?

Answer (score 1):

Voice and data use different frequency bands for transmission over `PSTN` wire. Usually data is transmitted on higher frequencies than voice.
On ATX side the incoming signal is divided into high (data) and low (voice) frequency components via frequency splitter.